# How to add header to different pages without rewriting it

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is there any way i can create some sort of constant that i can just use one word in my html document and add my header into it and making one change in the header will change the header for all the pages. This is so i dont have to copy and paste it to every page and make one change and have them apply to the header on all the pages.

Comment: Create the header as a separate .html file. Then use [AJAX](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/AJAX) to pull it into all the files you need it in.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Javascript` to edit the content and link the `JS File` in all of your HTML Documents.

You can also use `CSS` with `content` property and also link `CSS File` in all of your HTML Documents.